# How can I access the value of an instance that is inside map?

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary

I am trying to use some shared preferences methods such as `setStringList` and `getStringList` but when using the get and displaying its values ​​I get the following line on the console:

```
{0: Instance of 'SearchDelegateModel', 1: Instance of 'SearchDelegateModel'}
```

Here is the code:

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
  onPressed: () async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final busqueda = await showSearch(context: context, delegate: SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal("Buscar...", this.historialMenuPrincipal));
    if (busqueda != null) {
      historialMenuPrincipal.removeWhere((item) => item.apodo == busqueda.apodo);
      this.historialMenuPrincipal.insert(0, busqueda);
      final historialbusquedacastead = historialMenuPrincipal.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
      prefs.setStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences", historialbusquedacastead);
      var getpre = prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences");
      print(getpre.asMap()); // the print shows {0: Instance of 'SearchDelegateModel', 1: Instance of 'SearchDelegateModel'}
    }
  },
),
//////////
List MenuPrincipalViewproductFromJson(String str) => List<SearchDelegateModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(x)));
 SearchDelegateModel{
 String apodo;
 String name;
SearchDelegateModel({this.apodo,this.name})
}
factory SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return SearchDelegateModel(
name: parsedJson['name'],
        apodo : parsedJson['apodo'])}
```

Comment: Can you share `SearchDelegateModel`?

Comment: ``print(getpre.asMap().toJson().toString());`` should print the values instead of Instance of the object.

Comment: With this line I only managed to access a variable::
            final names = historialMenuPrincipal.map((e) => e.apodo).toList(); getpre.asMap()[0];   but i need all the variables. if i use only historialMenuPrincipal i can access only with historialMenuPrincipal[0].apodo

Answer (score 0):

Can you share `SearchDelegateModel`, or you can access you data model like this.

`print("${getpre[0].nameVariableInSearchDelegateModel}");`

Comment: I can not access as you are telling me and i updated the code.  busqueda = await showSearch is from search delegate

Comment: ```prefs.setStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences", historialbusquedacastead);
      var getpre = prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences");
      print(get[0].name); // you can use this
      getPre.forEach((x) => print(x.apodo); // or this to see the value from each list value
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, you could use this in your print line instead

```
getPre.forEach((e) => print(e.name));
```